# NPM Unmet peer dependency

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have a project with installed `React@15.4.1`

Now I want to add [this](https://github.com/dogfessional/react-swipeable) package, but this error appears:

```
-- UNMET PERR DEPENDENCY react@>=0.12.0 || ^15.0.0-0
npm WARN react-swipeable@3.9.2 requires a peer of react@>=0.12.0 || ^15.0.0-0
but none was installed
```

If I understand right, this package has React 0.12-15.0 versions in its peer dependencies, but my project uses higher version and that;s why I can't add this package to my project. So what is possible solution?

Comment: It is only a warning, so it should add correctly.  Otherwise raise an issue (or support this one: https://github.com/dogfessional/react-swipeable/issues/63)

Comment: this is my issue, but thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two are two things that can be done from your side,

You can make use of `React@15.0.0` instead of `React@15.4.1` in your `package.json`

Remove the entry for `React@15.4.1` and delete the `node_modules`. After that run the command

```
npm install
```

to install React@15.0.0 run command

```
npm install -S react@15.0.0
```

The second thing that you can do is to look for another npm module that is compatible with your version of React.